# The “Kunneth-type” morphism in equivariant $K$-theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, equivariant-cohomology

Suppose that one has two algebraic varieties with action of a reductive group  $G$: say, $X$ and $Y$.

There is an evident Kunneth-type morphism

$K_G(X) \otimes K_G(Y) \to K_G(X \times Y)$,

where the tensor product is over $R(G)$.

If $X$ is proper, and the diagonal in $X \times X$ is decomposable, it is an isomorphism.

Suppose now that $X$ is **not** proper, but has a decomposable diagonal. Suppose also that $Y$ is proper.

Is the morphism above still surjective/injective?

Many thanks!